# How to print message data in SK_MSG hook

Tags: c, linux, kernel, ebpf

I am running a `sk_msg` program. Here is my program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>

char LICENSE[] SEC("license") = "GPL";

SEC("sk_msg")
int http_state_machine(struct sk_msg_md *msg) {
  int err;
  int *msg_id_ptr;
  long len = (long)msg->data_end - (long)msg->data;
  if (len > 0) {
    bpf_printk("Message length: %ld\n", len);
  } else {
    bpf_printk("ERR: Message length is negative\n");
    return SK_PASS;
  }

  // Try to print the message
  char msg_str[300];
  if (len < 300) {
    bpf_printk("Message length is less than 300\n");
  } else {
    err = bpf_msg_pull_data(msg, 0, 300, 0);
    if (err < 0) {
      bpf_printk("ERR: bpf_msg_pull_data failed\n");
      return SK_PASS;
    }

    err = bpf_probe_read_kernel(msg_str, 300, msg->data);
    if (err < 0) {
      bpf_printk("ERR: bpf_probe_read_kernel failed\n");
      return SK_PASS;
    }
    bpf_printk("Socket Message: %s\n", msg_str);
  }

  return SK_PASS;
}
```

While the above does not give any errors, printing the `msg_str` also does not work. The output in `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_pipe` is as follows:

```
 ComposePostServ-1918515 [008] d...1 1322265.977032: bpf_trace_printk: Message length: 1295

 ComposePostServ-1918515 [008] d...1 1322265.977039: bpf_trace_printk: Socket Message: 

 ComposePostServ-1918516 [004] d...1 1322266.019906: bpf_trace_printk: Message length: 872

 ComposePostServ-1918516 [004] d...1 1322266.019914: bpf_trace_printk: Socket Message:
```

Can I not copy the `msg->data` into a `char[]` or should I use something else to print?

*Note:* I am also getting the same problem when I try to attach a `sk_skb` program instead (replacing `msg` with a `skb` in the above code). So I do not think this is because of a limitation of the `BPF_PROG_TYPE_SK_MSG`)

Comment: Any reason to use `bpf_probe_read_kernel`? Did you try reading the data directly with a `__builtin_memcpy` call?

Comment: I had first thought that `bpf_probe_read_kernel` is needed to read any kernel data. I tried using `__builtin_memcpy` and that gave me an error: `A call to built-in function 'memcpy' is not supported`. Based on a suggestion by @dylan-reimerink I tried using a manual copy by iterating over all elements, and that seems to work now. I'll experiment with it a bit and mark my question answered. Thanks!

Comment: It's weird that you couldn't use `__builtin_memcpy`. [Many BPF programs use it](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Atorvalds%2Flinux%20__builtin_memcpy%20path%3Asamples%2Fbpf&type=code).

Comment: Okay, so after some experimenting I realized that `__builtin_memcpy` requires a fixed integer for the length. My example above is simplified so I just use 300 there, but if instead I wanted to do something like `__builtin_memcpy(msg_str, msg->data, length)` then it shows the error that `A call to built-in function 'memcpy' is not supported`.

Comment: I guess the workaround is to either iterate and copy each element one by one. Or use `__builtin_memcpy` in small offsets.